# How to override a readonly property in a subclass of CLLocation?

Tags: objective-c, properties, cllocation, subclassing

I am subclassing `CLLocation` in order to add a property:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import CoreLocation;

@interface MyLocation : CLLocation

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;

@end
```

The problem is I need to be able to update `MyLocation`'s `coordinate` property, which is declared as `readonly` in the superclass:

```
// CLLocation.h
@property(readonly, nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

Following some similar answers here, I created a private extension where I redeclare `coordinate` as `readwrite`:

```
@interface MyLocation ()

@property(nonatomic, assign, readwrite) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@end
```

Since the compiler complains about that, I also added the `@dynamic` keyword:

```
@implementation MyLocation

@dynamic coordinate;

@end
```

Then I create a method to update an instance of my subclass with another coordinate:

```
@implementation MyLocation

@dynamic coordinate;

-(void)updateCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate
{
    self.coordinate = newCoordinate;
}

@end
```

The problem is when I call `-updateCoordinate` I get a crash with the message *`-[MyLocation setCoordinate:]`: unrecognized selector sent to instance* meaning that what I did doesn't work as I hopped. I guess there is no setter for `coordinate` in `CLLocation.m`?

Can someone explain what's going on here and suggest any solution?

Comment: Never override anything within a Category. Imagine several Categories override the same property/method/anything. What is supposed to be used? I would wrap CLLocation (instead of sub-classing it) and make the `CLLocation` a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just make a copy of the CLLocation in this case. It's immutable for a reason. For example:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)new
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)old{


    new = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(old.coordinate.latitude, -1.000028276362)
                                             altitude:old.altitude
                                   horizontalAccuracy:old.horizontalAccuracy
                                     verticalAccuracy:old.verticalAccuracy
                                            timestamp:old.timestamp] autorelease];

    return new 
}
```

Comment: I agree _it's immutable for a reason_, but out of curiosity can you clarify why my approach doesn't work?

Comment: shallowThought summed it up in their comment. :)